# Оформление прямой речи по-корректному

Tags: прямая-речь

Как правильно?

`«Незачем нам больше общаться», – начал Джек. «Почему?» – спросила Кейт, и ей Джек ответил: «Мне с тобой скучно».`

`«Незачем нам больше общаться», – начал Джек. «Почему?» – спросила Кейт, и ей Джек ответил: – «Мне с тобой скучно».`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два варианта:

> — Незачем нам больше общаться, – начал Джек.
>
> — Почему? — спросила Кейт, и ей Джек ответил:
>
> — Мне с тобой скучно;

> «Незачем нам больше общаться», – начал Джек. «Почему?» – спросила Кейт, и ей Джек ответил: «Мне с тобой скучно».

---

В первом варианте реплики оформлены в виде **диалога**, поэтому везде стоят тире, но нет кавычек.

Во втором варианте стоят кавычки, но нет **тире**, т. е. оформлено в виде **прямой речи**.

---

Использовать тире в прямой речи — всë равно что использовать кавычки в диалоге, т. е. так делать некорректно. Нужно выбрать либо диалог, либо прямую речь.

Comment: Максим, и то, и другое – прямая речь:  с кавычками называется *в строку (в подбор)*,  с абзаца и с тире – диалог.

Comment: @Максим Ваш ответ, считаю, не является корректным. 1. *В первом варианте реплики оформлены в виде диалога, поэтому везде стоят тире, но нет кавычек.* А у вас кавычки есть:  — Мне с тобой **скучно»;** И ещё смущающая точка с запятой. 2. *Во втором варианте стоят кавычки, но нет тире, т. е. оформлено в виде прямой речи.* Ну как же — нет тире? Есть. Аж два. 3. Оформление в виде цитирования тоже не является правильным. Вы же ведь *ничего* не цитируете.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Извините за ошибку с лишней кавычкой, сейчас исправлю. А по поводу тире я имел в виду, что их не будет перед репликой, но если слова автора идут после прямой речи, то тире нужно ставить. А точка с запятой разделяет два цитирования. Да, я ничего не цитирую, но так удобней оформить.